# SQL - how to group transactions for a certain date pattern?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table with transactions data and want to count the number of records for each transaction_date. The date format looks like this: `2018-11-12T01:07:36.000+0000`

I tried this query but it does not return anything. What could be the problem with my query?

I expect the output to look like `transaction_date`, `number_of_transactions`

```
SELECT 
transaction_date, COUNT(*)
FROM main.transactions 
WHERE transaction_date LIKE 2018-11-30
GROUP BY 
transaction_date
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

**UPD:** Also is it possible to group by date and every hour of the date (from 00 to 23)?

Comment: 2018-11-30 = 1977. Use single quotes.

Comment: You should not attempt to use `Like` with date/time values, it is for matching strings. Use date/time functions.

Comment: @samba . . . Your update is a separate question.  It should be asked as a *new* question, particularly because this question already has answers.

Comment: yes it is just include in after group by in having clause as having `To_char(Transaction_Date,'hh') like '[00-23]`

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja it did not work

Comment: what is the error you are getting i think it should work. or else if theres a problem in like '00-24' replace it with >0 and <=24 can you please share the output of the above query i wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Trim off the time part to get the date:

```
SELECT 
transaction_date::date, COUNT(*) xact_count
FROM main.transactions 
WHERE transaction_date::date = '2018-11-30'::date
GROUP BY 
transaction_date::date
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

And use equality for the date stamp, not the string function "LIKE"

I saw your question below about the hourly grouping.

```
SELECT 
date_trunc('hour',transaction_date), COUNT(*) xact_count
FROM main.transactions 
GROUP BY 
date_trunc('hour', transaction_date)
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using date() function

```
SELECT 
date(transaction_date) as tdate, COUNT(*)
FROM main.transactions 
WHERE date(transaction_date) ='2018-11-30'
GROUP BY 
date(transaction_date)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    transaction_date::date, COUNT(*)
    FROM main.transactions 
    WHERE transaction_date::date ='2018-11-30'
    GROUP BY 
    transaction_date::date
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should include `trunc(transaction_date)` in where clause. trunc would remove the time part in your date as currently it is taking date-time n you are matching with only date so it is likely to give no result.

Answer (score 1):

Use date with `quotation` as `'2018-11-30'` or `date'2018-11-30'`

```
with transactions(transaction_date) as
(
 SELECT timestamp'2018-11-30T01:07:36.000+0000' union all
 SELECT timestamp'2018-11-30T03:28:36.000+0000' union all
 SELECT timestamp'2018-11-12T03:28:36.000+0000'   
)
SELECT transaction_date::date, 
       COUNT(*) as number_of_transactions
  FROM transactions 
 WHERE date_trunc('day', transaction_date::date) = date'2018-11-30'
 GROUP BY transaction_date::date
 ORDER BY number_of_transactions DESC;

transaction_date    number_of_transactions
------------------- ----------------------
30.11.2018 00:00:00          2
```

and try to use alias for your `ORDER BY` clauses.

You may also prefer making `WHERE` condition

`WHERE cast(transaction_date as date) = '2018-11-30'` as another alternative style.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/PZHO94090)

Comment: @KirkRoybal ..  :)

Comment: For some reason it returns not only dates for dates like '2018-11-30' but also for '2018-10-12'

Comment: @samba try this link : https://rextester.com/LAGZC28719 that also returns 2 as count.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan could you please advise with how to group by date and every hour of the date (from 00 to 23)?

Comment: @samba edited the post with respect to timestamp data type.